# Filter string keys of array from a string in a Javascript object format in an SQL table

Tags: javascript, sql, google-cloud-platform

I would like to filter out keys (given in an array of strings - ["key2"]) in a given column on an SQL table, say:

**{ key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 }**

```
 |--row---|-object--|---value----|

 |---1----|--obj1---|--sum(obj1)-|

 |---2----|--obj2---|--sum(obj2)-|

 |---3----|--obj3---|--sum(obj3)-|
```

I want to be able to do this with the use of SQL and filter all keys of an array for each row in parallel.

So for example, if I had these objects:

obj1 = "{ key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 }"

obj2 = "{ key1: val1, key2: val2 }"

obj3 = "{ key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5 }"

and an array of ["key1", "key4"]

I would get new table with new objects and new values as:

obj1 = "{ key2: val2, key3: val3 }"              ,  val = val2+val3

obj2 = "{ key2: val2 }"                          ,  val = val2

obj3 = "{ key2: val2, key3: val3, key5: val5 }"  ,  val = val2+val3+val5

Is it possible?

I tried to use JSON_EXTRACTOR in order to extract the object as a JSON format and manipulate the rows with the filter function one by one but it is not very efficient when I think about it, and it is not using the query to do the filtering.

Comment: Found a solution using JSON_EXTRACT:

dynamically append " JSON_EXTRACT(object, '$.obj1') as obj1, " strings to a SELECT. 
* about the efficiency - I don't know yet if it is the best solution and if it is scalable.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding you are using MySQL. The way that you have found I think is the proper, according to [this article](https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/) about `JSON_EXTRACT()` points that:

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}', '$.b') AS 'Result';`

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) you can find the official documentation.

You can always use the [Query Execution Plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html) to verify the efficiency of your queries, but it also depend on your tables, columns, indexes and the conditions in the Where clause.